# Modifying a parsed CSV file output, swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, csv, parsing

I have the below text file inside my Xcode project:

```
Section Designation,Mass per metre (kg/m),Depth of section h (mm),Width of section b (mm),Web thickness tw (mm),Flange thickness tf (mm),Root radius r (mm),Depth between fillets d (mm)
1016x305x584,584.0,1056.0,314.0,36.0,64.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x494,494.0,1036.0,309.0,31.0,54.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x438,438.0,1026.0,305.0,26.9,49.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x415,415.0,1020.0,304.0,26.0,46.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x393,392.7,1015.9,303.0,24.4,43.9,30.0,868.1
1016x305x350,350.0,1008.0,302.0,21.1,40.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x314,314.3,999.9,300.0,19.1,35.9,30.0,868.1
1016x305x272,272.3,990.1,300.0,16.5,31.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x249,248.7,980.1,300.0,16.5,26.0,30.0,868.1
1016x305x222,222.0,970.3,300.0,16.0,21.1,30.0,868.1
```

And I wrote the below code inside my ViewController in order to parse the data and make them into a usable Array, which I am intending to use later on to fill my UITable:

```
class UniversalBeamsViewController: UIViewController {

    var  data:[[String:String]] = []

    var  columnTitles:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

       convertCSV(file: "data")

  }

    func readDataFromFile(file:String) -> String!{

        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "txt")

            else {

                return nil

        }

        do {

            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)

            return contents

        } catch {

            print("File Read Error for file \(filepath)")

            return nil

        }

    }

    func cleanRows(file: String)->String{

        var cleanFile = readDataFromFile(file: file)

        cleanFile = cleanFile!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")

        cleanFile = cleanFile!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")

        return cleanFile!

    }

    func getStringFieldsForRow(row:String, delimiter:String)-> [String]{

        return row.components(separatedBy: delimiter)

    }

    func convertCSV(file:String){

        let rows = cleanRows(file: file).components(separatedBy: "\n")

        if rows.count > 0 {

            data = []

            columnTitles = getStringFieldsForRow(row: rows.first!,delimiter:",")

            for row in rows {

                let fields = getStringFieldsForRow(row: row,delimiter: ",")

                if fields.count != columnTitles.count {continue}

                var dataRow = [String:String]()

                for (index,field) in fields.enumerated(){

                    let fieldName = columnTitles[index]

                    dataRow[fieldName] = field

                }

                data += [dataRow]

            }

        } else {

            print("No data in file")

        }

        print(data)

    }

}
```

However, when the convertCSV method gets executed I get the below as the array output:

```
[["Web thickness tw (mm)": "Web thickness tw (mm)", "Depth of section h (mm)": "Depth of section h (mm)", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "Flange thickness tf (mm)", "Section Designation": "Section Designation", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "Mass per metre (kg/m)", "Width of section b (mm)": "Width of section b (mm)", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "Depth between fillets d (mm)", "Root radius r (mm)": "Root radius r (mm)"], ["Web thickness tw (mm)": "36.0", "Depth of section h (mm)": "1056.0", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Width of section b (mm)": "314.0", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "584.0", "Section Designation": "1016x305x584", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "64.0"], ["Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "54.0", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "31.0", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "494.0", "Section Designation": "1016x305x494", "Depth of section h (mm)": "1036.0", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Width of section b (mm)": "309.0"], ["Section Designation": "1016x305x438", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Width of section b (mm)": "305.0", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "26.9", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "49.0", "Depth of section h (mm)": "1026.0", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "438.0"], ["Depth of section h (mm)": "1020.0", "Section Designation": "1016x305x415", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "26.0", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "415.0", "Width of section b (mm)": "304.0", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "46.0", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1"], ["Flange thickness tf (mm)": "43.9", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "392.7", "Width of section b (mm)": "303.0", "Depth of section h (mm)": "1015.9", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "24.4", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Section Designation": "1016x305x393"], ["Web thickness tw (mm)": "21.1", "Depth of section h (mm)": "1008.0", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "350.0", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "40.0", "Section Designation": "1016x305x350", "Width of section b (mm)": "302.0"], ["Depth of section h (mm)": "999.9", "Width of section b (mm)": "300.0", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "19.1", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "35.9", "Section Designation": "1016x305x314", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "314.3"], ["Web thickness tw (mm)": "16.5", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "272.3", "Section Designation": "1016x305x272", "Depth of section h (mm)": "990.1", "Width of section b (mm)": "300.0", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "31.0", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1"], ["Mass per metre (kg/m)": "248.7", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Depth of section h (mm)": "980.1", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "26.0", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "16.5", "Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Width of section b (mm)": "300.0", "Section Designation": "1016x305x249"], ["Depth between fillets d (mm)": "868.1", "Mass per metre (kg/m)": "222.0", "Flange thickness tf (mm)": "21.1", "Root radius r (mm)": "30.0", "Width of section b (mm)": "300.0", "Web thickness tw (mm)": "16.0", "Depth of section h (mm)": "970.3", "Section Designation": "1016x305x222"]]
```

And as it can be seen from the above output, the column titles get printed inside the array and occupies the whole first array inside of the big main array. I do not way the column titles to be printed as part of the big array I would like to obtain. Any idea what part of the code I need to modiy to make this happen?

Regards,
Shadi.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop

```
for row in rows
```

will include all rows including the first one with column names, one way to solve this is to iterate over an index but start from 1 rather than 0

```
for i in 1..<rows.count {
    let row = rows[i]
    // same as before...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the field names of the first line and then you iterate the **entire** array which includes also the first line.

Use an index based loop and start with 1 (second index)

```
func convertCSV(file:String){

    let rows = cleanRows(file: file).components(separatedBy: "\n")
    if !rows.isEmpty {
        data = []
        columnTitles = getStringFieldsForRow(row: rows.first!,delimiter:",")
        for i in 1..<rows.count {
            let fields = getStringFieldsForRow(row: rows[i],delimiter: ",")
            if fields.count != columnTitles.count {continue}
            var dataRow = [String:String]()
            for (index,field) in fields.enumerated(){
                let fieldName = columnTitles[index]
                dataRow[fieldName] = field
            }
            data += [dataRow]
        }
    } else {
        print("No data in file")
    }
    print(data)

}
```